# Disable bxSlider if there is only one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bxslider

I have a slider on all of my pages, but I would like to disable it if there is only one slide. I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work correctly. Here is the code I am using:

```
    var slider = $('.bxslidertwo').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    pagerType:'full',
    autoHidePager: true,

});

var numberOfImages = $('.bxslidertwo li').length;

if (numberOfImages > 1) {
    slider.reloadSlider();
} else {
    slider.destroySlider();
}
```

Any help that can be offered with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Does instantiating it only if there is an image work? In that case, try this:

```
var numberOfImages = $('.bxslidertwo li').length;

if( numberOfImages > 1 ) {

    var slider = $('.bxslidertwo').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        pagerType:'full',
        autoHidePager: true,

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think I figured it out. I forgot that bxSlider automatically adds a clone of the first and last slide, even if there is only one. So there are actually three list items being produced, not one. So I had to change my code to be if there is more than 3 list items, do the slider. That seems to have worked.